# How to save multiple files in loop with original filenames

Tags: r, loops, save, filenames

I'm trying to import several SAS datafiles from a folder and then save them back into the folder as R dataframes with the same original SAS dataset name.  Everything works except I can't figure out how to save the file with the original file name (i.e., I can't figure out the x in > save(xxx, file = ...).

The code I've tried is as follows:

```
path <- "path to folder with sas files"

list.files(pattern=".sas7bdat$")
list.filenames<-list.files(pattern=".sas7bdat$")

for (i in 1:length(list.filenames)){
  assign(list.filenames[i], read_sas(list.filenames[i]))
  filename <- paste(list.filenames[i]) 
  save(list.filenames[i],file = paste0(path, paste(list.filenames[i], "Rdat", sep = ".")))
  }
```

doesn't work...

```
for (i in 1:length(list.filenames)){
  assign(list.filenames[i], read_sas(list.filenames[i]))
  filename <- paste(list.filenames[i]) 
  save(list.filenames[[i]],file = paste0(path, paste(list.filenames[i], "Rdat", sep = ".")))
  }
```

doesn't work

```
for (i in 1:length(list.filenames)){
  assign(list.filenames[i], read_sas(list.filenames[i]))
  filename <- paste(list.filenames[i]) 
  save(filename,file = paste0(path, paste(list.filenames[i], "Rdat", sep = ".")))
  }
```

Any help on figuring out how to save the files with the original names from list.filenames[i]?

Comment: You can grab individual elements of a list by index with list[[i]]. Try putting all of your calls to the list in double, rather than single brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "list" argument of `save`. Something like

```
path <- "path to folder with sas files"

list.filenames <- list.files(path, pattern="\\.sas7bdat$")

for (i in list.filenames) {
    datName <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(i)
    assign(datName, read_sas(i))
    save(list=datName, file = paste0(path, paste(datName, "Rdat", sep = ".")))
}
```

would work. Also, I imagine you want `pattern=".sas7bdat$"` as `pattern="\\.sas7bdat$`, since "." is a wildcard in regex.

Comment: Thanks.  This still runs into the problem I was trying to solve.  It saves the tibble in a folder with the appropriate name but when I load it back into R all the dataframes are called "tb".  I'm trying to take a sas datafile named, for example, "stock", save to a folder as a tibble or dataframe as "stock" then when I independently load it back into R it will be named "stock", not "tb".  If you have any other ideas for this I'd appreciate it as I'm pretty stuck.  Thanks.

Comment: I see. I've amended my answer.

Comment: That works perfect.  Thank you so much for helping me out, this would have taken me forever.  I've never see the tools::file_path_sans_ext().  Thanks again, I really appreciate your assistance.